# Variable After Assignment is still Undefined in Callback Function in Javascript for PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

So I have the following used for phantomjs:

```
  var time = 1490543999999999;
  var endTime = time - 518400000000 * 10;
  var mintime = time - 518399999999;
  console.log("mintime after assignment is"+mintime);
  var loopnumber = 6;

  page.open('https://myactivity.google.com/item?min=' + mintime + '&max=' + time + '&product=5,6,7,10,11,12,13,15,19,20,25,27,28', callback);

  function callback() {
    console.log("inside callback and loopnumber is "+loopnumber+"and time is "+time+", and mintime is "+mintime+'. URL: https://myactivity.google.com/item?min=' + mintime + '&max=' + time + '&product=5,6,7,10,11,12,13,15,19,20,25,27,28');
    page.render('/Users/jMac-NEW/Documents/FILEMAKER OCLC/login_test33.7_brkpoint' + loopnumber + '.png');
    fs.write('/Users/jMac-NEW/Documents/FILEMAKER OCLC/login_test33.7_brkpoint' + loopnumber + 'html.html', page.content, 'w');
    time -= 518400000000;
    loopnumber++;
    if (time > endTime) {
      var mintime = time - 518399999999;
      page.open('https://myactivity.google.com/item?min=' + mintime + '&max=' + time + '&product=5,6,7,10,11,12,13,15,19,20,25,27,28', callback);
    }
    else {
      phantom.exit();
    }
  }
```

This is output for the first console.log:

```
mintime after assignment is1490025600000000
```

But when it comes to the console.log in the callback(), this is the output:

```
inside callback and loopnumber is 6and time is 1490543999999999, and mintime is undefined. URL: https://myactivity.google.com/item?min=undefined&max=1490543999999999&product=5,6,7,10,11,12,13,15,19,20,25,27,28
```

Why is mintime = undefined, when the other variables (loopnumber and time) are not?

Comment: The second declaration of `mintime` inside the function shadows the outer declaration.

Comment: @user5090812 but why does it end up undefined? even with the second declaration it is still a number

Answer (score 0):

There's a concept in Javascript called *hoisting* - if a variable is declared **after** it's been used, script interpreter automatically moves it's declaration to the top of current scope internally.

So your script actually reads to js like this:

```
function callback() {
    var mintime; // <-- declaration moved here

    // mintime is not yet defined
    console.log("and time is "+time+", and mintime is "+mintime);
    // ...
    if (time > endTime) {
      mintime = time - 518399999999; // it's been declared already and now it's defined
    }
    else {
      phantom.exit();
    }
  }
```

So the solution is simple: remove `var` from assignment to `mintime` in callback, this way variable will be assigned to the outer (window) scope `mintime`, just like you wanted.